# why the compiler don't give me error?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("clear");
    int *pt = malloc(2 * sizeof *pt);
    int *tmp = NULL;
    int i;

    pt[0] = 44;
    pt[1] = 9;
    printf("pt[0] : %d\n", pt[0]);
    printf("pt[1] : %d\n", pt[1]);
    tmp = realloc(pt, 3 * sizeof *pt);
    if (!tmp) {
        printf("merde alors\n");
    } else {
        pt = tmp;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            pt[i] = i + 1;
            printf("pt[%d] : %d\n", i, pt[i]);
        }
    }
    //the compiler should give me an error here, because I try use an unallocated memory:
    printf("pt[%d] : %d\n", i + 8, pt[i + 8]);
    free(pt);
    return 0;
}
```

hello everybody :) 
I don't understand, as you see, I try to use an unallocated memory, so I expect receive an aggressive error from the compiler.
excuse my bad English.
thank you for your time :)
[Valgrind report :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQQJ6.png)

Comment: Some things you just have to debug. It can't show errors that only appear at runtime.

Comment: Even if the array was hard coded, the C compiler will not prevent you indexing beyond its bounds. For a pointer, the compiler may not even know how much memory you will allocate at runtime. It's up to you to check array indexing.

Comment: Depending on your development environment you might find some debugging tool like valgrind useful. Valgrind is able to pinpoint this kind of bugs at runtime. http://valgrind.org/

Comment: You should start by formating your code correctly.

Comment: I can confirm @HenrikCarlqvist's suggestion works; `valgrind` reports one invalid write (line 20) and two invalid reads (lines 15 and 21). It also notes that there is lots of memory still allocated at exit. (It did not like your line `system("clear")` *at all* – I had to remove that first.)

Comment: @Jongware system("clear") is to clear my terminal :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  //the compiler should give me an error here, because i try use an unallocated memory:   
  printf("pt[%d] : %d\n", i+8, pt[i+8]);
```

Normally you don't get such errors from the compiler, it is up to you to keep track of it. That's the beauty or dark side of C. And if such issue occurs that is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB), results of which are even worse.

So it is up to you. Some compiler flags or static analyzers may help you sometimes when there is obvious array out of bounds access.

The same holds for many other related issues, on which compiler doesn't warn you and you get UB - that's why in languages such as C or C++, you really need to know what you are doing.

Again in this particular case, if the array size you are specifying at run time, compiler might not even know what the array size will be - so it can't give you an error. Even if it knew, the compiler will not always tell you about array out of bounds access.

Comment: @younesky you are welcome, you can further read more about UB if you are interested in languages such as C or C++

Comment: i love C, it is hard, but it's gave me most control

Comment: @younesky: you can use `valgrind` for this kind of error tracking.

Comment: @chqrlie Team Ubuntu says: https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/valgrind
Valgrind is not able to detect some abnormalities related to the code. For example, it does not check the indexes on tables outside table declared statically

Comment: @younesky: did you try?  `valgrind` should be able to instrument `malloc` to detect buffer overruns in allocated memory.  You may need to pass special flags to it.  Read the `man` page.

Comment: @chqrlie yes i try it now, I compile white -g parametre like this: gcc dayTab.c -o dayTab -g    and then test with :  valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --leak-resolution=high --show-reachable=yes ./dayTab   and  to get profil :  valgrind --tool=callgrind ./dayTab

Comment: and result is : All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible

Comment: @younesky: too bad, I thought it was more effective.  A very good tool nonetheless.

Comment: @chqrlie you can see Valgrind report in the screenshot image  http://i.stack.imgur.com/lQQJ6.png

Comment: @younesky in your screenshot you see "invalid read of size 4" at daytab.c:26. That is exactly the error you are searching for with the comment //the compiler should give me an error here... As you now see "no leaks possible" only means that your code no longer have any memory leaks. Did you edit your code to add free(pt) after Red Lexus did his test?

Comment: @HenrikCarlqvist thank you, and no I don't edit my code after the the Red Lexus test

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't check to see if the memory you're accessing exists at compile time. That is all done at runtime, by your operating system. It isn't C itself that causes segmentation faults to occur, but actually your operating system telling C to stop.

Comment: I didn't see that Giorgi had already wrote this response, my bad! :)

Comment: that's fine there can be multiple answers, if you think yours is adding something